# rm -rf cannot delete session files

Tags: nginx, php, session

#### 1. list the files in session dir

```
$ /var/lib/php/sessions$ sudo ls -la
total 20
drwx-wx-wt 2 root     root     12288 May 20 14:26 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root     root      4096 Feb 26 21:15 ..
-rw------- 1 www-data www-data     0 May 20 14:26 sess_716a24lf4tsnmfucpq50uf1pk7
-rw------- 1 www-data www-data   124 May 20 14:26 sess_fkif8ed8k85olh53q9so1cd6s3
-rw------- 1 www-data www-data     0 May 20 14:25 sess_ov6nrn16gg81i44u9angk3bls6
```

#### 2. sudo delete all files

```
$ /var/lib/php/sessions$ sudo rm -rf ./*
```

#### 3. But the session files still existed!

```
$ /var/lib/php/sessions$ sudo ls -la    
total 20
drwx-wx-wt 2 root     root     12288 May 20 14:26 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root     root      4096 Feb 26 21:15 ..
-rw------- 1 www-data www-data     0 May 20 14:26 sess_716a24lf4tsnmfucpq50uf1pk7
-rw------- 1 www-data www-data   124 May 20 14:26 sess_fkif8ed8k85olh53q9so1cd6s3
-rw------- 1 www-data www-data     0 May 20 14:25 sess_ov6nrn16gg81i44u9angk3bls6
```

Comment: Did you made up the output or are the timestamps correct? I would expect the files to get new timestamps when PHP rewrites them.

Comment: I use stat sess_716a24lf4tsnmfucpq50uf1pk7 before and after rm -rf, the timestamp are same.

Comment: You can easily debug this: with `sudo echo ./*` you'll get what gets actually removed with your _read mail -really -fast_ (`rm -rf`).

Comment: I get this result:
`$ sudo echo ./*`
./*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that **path name expansion occurs BEFORE the `sudo`**. The path name expansion for `./*` doesn't have permission to see the directory contents. Therefore, it would not get expanded to `rm -rf ./sess_716a24lf4tsnmfucpq50uf1pk7 ./sess_fkif8ed8k85olh53q9so1cd6s3 ./sess_ov6nrn16gg81i44u9angk3bls6` as supposed – and as it would, if the whole command was run as `root`.

You can launch a new terminal inside `sudo`. Try:

```
sudo sh -c "rm -rf /var/lib/php/sessions/*"
```

Notice that I used the full path because it's much more safe than a relative path. Once a colleague typed `/` instead of `./` inside `sudo rm -rf`. You can imagine what happened: unnecessary restoring task for me... and one user less in the sudoers list.

Comment: Tried this getting "sh: 1: Cannot fork" ... :(

Answer (score 1):

This is strange, maybe new sessions are created right after you remove them?

What happens if you try to remove a single file?

`sudo rm sess_716a24lf4tsnmfucpq50uf1pk7`

Does the file get removed?

Comment: yes it works when I remove the single file ! 
And the session recreate when i refresh the web site

Comment: Hm, can you try "echo ./" to see if there are any odd names files in there (and `rm -- ./*` to delete). I would especially remove the -f option to get error messages.

Comment: Yes PHP will recreate the sessions from Cache, restarting Apache should help with that.

Comment: `sudo service php7.0-fpm restart && sudo service nginx restart` the session still there

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer right now. A helpful, troubleshooting comment, but a comment nonetheless, and as such it belongs in the comment area.

Answer (score 1):

You have not indicated which user you are running as. However, the `$` prompt indicates that you are running as a standard user, which is most likely not `www-data`.

So, the issue is that file system permissions prevent you from deleting the files, as you can see from the `ls -l` output.

Comment: Couldn't the `sudo` mentioned in the question help with that? ;)

Comment: I can sudo to rm one session file, so the problem should not about permission

Comment: The permissions doesn't prevent from deleting files (because of `sudo`) but from seeing them (because of "`$`"). See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Esa Jokinen](https://serverfault.com/users/274176/esa-jokinen) [said](https://serverfault.com/a/851261/591003) often you can't delete session files even with command like `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/php/sessions/*` because a path name expansion occurs BEFORE the sudo.

You can try another command like `sudo sh -c "rm -rf /var/lib/php/sessions/*"` but if you have tons of files you'll get a response like `rm: Argument list too long` because the list of session files is usually very huge (up to millions of files).

I propose a really simple way:

1. Create a new folder *sessions_new*: `mkdir /var/lib/php/sessions_new`
2. Set the same permissions as for old *sessions* directory: `sudo chmod --reference=sessions sessions_new`
3. Do the same with ownership: `sudo chown --reference=sessions sessions_new`
4. Kill it! `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/php/sessions`
5. You don't need to wait a result for a long time. You can check it immediately in a new terminal window by `sudo find /var/lib/php/sessions/. -type f|wc -l`. This command counts the number of files inside your *sessions* folder. Run it two times. If the second time you run the command, you get a lower number than the first time, then the process is going in the right direction.
6. Wait for a long time :P
7. When process has finished just rename the *session_new* directory: `sudo mv /var/lib/php/sessions_new /var/lib/php/sessions`